# Can you now get villagers through zombie spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I see people playing around with Minecraft version 1.4, and I see that zombie spawners now also spawn infected villagers.

On another video I saw how you can cure an infected villager. I wonder if you could cure the villagers that are spawned from the zombie spawner.

This would be great for me. I have been wanting to bring villagers to my base, but it would be quite a project as the nearest village is miles away. I have a zombie spawner just under my base, so that would be ideal.

**EDIT:**

I answered the question bellow with screenshots. Here is a video I made of the system:

Comment: We won't know for sure until the actual release of 1.4. Great question though!

Comment: I'm playing with the pre-1.4 12w36a snapshot, and at least in Creative I can't get villager zombies to accept Golden Apples. Splash potions of weakness (which the wiki says is step one in curing them) don't appear to affect them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Read further in the wiki and it should tell you that it takes a few minutes for the cure to take effect.

Comment: @MBraedley I did read that. What I haven't figured out is how to effect them with a Weakness potion first. My test subjects appear immune. It's possible that only zombie villagers that were originally villagers (not spawned from an egg or spawner) can be cured.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well it is still working in creative for me. Just throw the splash potion on the infected villager. After that just leftclick him with a normal golden apple, and he starts shaking. After a few mins he is cured. I will work on the spawner in my survival world today, I will set up a quick test, let's see if it works.

Comment: I'm running 12w36a right now—maybe it's changed or bugged in this prerelease. (And that would be why this Q can't be answered yet. ;)

Comment: Wait, I am also on 12w36a. Does your villager shake after you clicked him with the apple?

Comment: No. As I've said, the Weakness splash potion is, for some reason, having no effect. Since I can't get step 1 to work, I can't move on to step 2 with the apple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually don't answer my own question, but in this case I have to I guess.

I am running Minecraft pre-release 12w36a and I can confirm that you can cure infected villagers spawned from dungeon zombie spawners in survival mode.

I had a zombie spawner underneath my base that I never destroyed, I am glad I kept it. I set up a small killing device for killing the unwanted zombies, and waited for a infected villager. In my case it spawned one every 30 zombies or so.

When I got one I used a splash potion of weakness (water bottle + fermented spider eye + gunpowder). As soon as I threw it I got my golden apple in my hand, and just right-clicked the villager. At this point he started shaking.

While he was shaking, I waited around. About 5 minutes later he turned into a normal villager.

At this point I wanted to know if he would despawn, so I went exploring in my world, slept for a few days, and went to the nether a few times. When I came back he was still standing there, which was great.

---

I do not know if this will stay in the game. I will update the game once in a while to see if it still works in the snapshots.

For now I will work on setting up my village, I am glad I don't have to build the 1000+ block railway anymore.

---

**I can confirm this works in 1.4.2, see the video in the question for more details.**

Comment: I have a question: what do the pistons do?

Comment: Look at the video in the question for more details.